# How to return a generator in Python

Tags: python, generator

I am thinking of designing my function to return a generator in combination with a database query. but having some question on the concept of iterators

```
def func():
    sql =" select some rows "
    dbconn = "connect and open to dtabase code"
    ret = ( execute(sql)  ) <----- returning a generator?
    dbclose <----  I close the db connection here, but it gives me error
    return ret
```

The question is, when i iterate the generator in the main function, i hit "error on closed cursor".  Should i close or not close it in the func()? I suppose when the call to func() end, the dbconn variable will be out of scope and i shouldn't have to worry about closing?

```
 # main function
 for it in func():
     do something with it
 close dbconn here?
```

How should i design this? returing a data structure like a list would be better?
thanks

Comment: It is not really useful to return an generator over 'ret' here since it is fetched into memory anyway at that point. Just pass the reference to the list. If you want generators here you should pass the database cursor.

Comment: `dbclose` does not do anything! Did you mean `dbclose()`?

Comment: Eric, they are just pseudocode.

Comment: maybe you should change the question title as "how to return a DB querry as a generator?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [Context Manager](http://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html), e.g. (contains some pseudocode):

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def func():
    sql =" select some rows "
    dbconn = "connect and open to dtabase code"
    yield execute(sql)  # returns this really a generator?
    dbclose #pseudocode, you probably want to put this in a try/finally block

with func() as result:
    for it in result:
         do something with it
```

Of course this is only useful if `execute(sql)` really returns a generator. If you put all data into a list (and thus into memory) before closing the connection, your problem will be obsolete.

```
def func():
    sql =" select some rows "
    dbconn = "connect and open to dtabase code"
    ret = list( execute(sql)  ) 
    dbclose # no problem here, since all data is already fetched
    return ret
```

---

In response to your comment:

If your database adapter follows the python DB API spec, an efficient way is to fetch a bunch of rows with `fetchmany` multiple times.

The following code fetches rows in chunks of 100, and explicitly calls `dbclose` when the execution leaves the `with` block:

```
def cursor_iter(cursor, num_of_rows=100):
    while True:
        rows = cursor.fetchmany(num_of_rows)
        if not rows: break
        for row in rows:
            yield row

@contextmanager
def func():
    sql = "select some rows"
    dbconn = connect_and_open_database()
    cursor = dbconn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    yield cursor_iter(cursor)
    dbclose()

with func() as result:
    for row in result: 
        do_something(row)
```

Comment: hi, execute doesn;t return generator. it is common db execute command. returns rows selected, or insert/delete etc commands.

Comment: thanks. i look up yield, that's what to use when creating generator. i guess i would use this and see if it works.

Comment: What database connector are you using? Does it follow the python DB API spec? You know, the thing with `connection.cursor()` and `cursor.fetchall()` :-) ? If it does, it would make it certainly easier... (I don't see any use of a cursor in your code, but maybe it's so because it's only pseudocode?)

Comment: Hi, thanks. the database is fine. now its whether i should just store in a list or use a generator and then iterate the items at main(). i guess either way works. Just that in terms of efficiency would there be any difference. eg if the select returns too many rows, storing into a list might be memory hogging, for example

Comment: @dorothy See my edit. I added an example of how to fetch rows in chunks using an generator with `cursor.fetchmany`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience on using database, but I think you should retrieve the query results and return it as a list. If you really need an iterator (but I cant see why), then return an iterator over the list `ret`:

```
def func():
    sql =" select some rows "
    dbconn = "connect and open to dtabase code"
    ret = execute(sql)              # a list
    dbclose()
    return (elmt for elmt in ret)   # return an iterator over ret
```

Now, if their exist a way to retrieve the *nth* element of a query, something like `execute(sql, n)` which return `None` if `n` is too big, then you could use a yield:

```
 def func():
    sql =" select some rows "
    dbconn = "connect and open to dtabase code"

    n = 0
    ret = execute(sql,n)    # return the n-th element
    while ret is not None:
        yield ret
        n += 1
        ret = execute(sql,n)

    dbclose()
```

Now, this is not what I would recommend, mainly because the connection to the db stays open while the iterator is not finished. And it might never happens if something fails or is badly designed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot try to manipulate a cursor after you have closed the database connection
I will try with this approach:

```
def func(params):
    sql = "query to execute"
    cursor = execute(sql, params)
    return cursor.fetchall() # retrieves all posible results as a sequence of sequences,
                             # i.g. list of tuples(*)

### Main ###
# Open database connection
# Create cursor
for elem in func(): # Call to retrieve desired element's method and do something with that
    # Do something
# Close cursor
# Close database connection
```

(*) http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/

I hope it helps